# How to disable Hazelcast distributed IExecutorService on certain nodes for security purposes?

Tags: java, security, cluster-computing, distributed, hazelcast

Is there a way to disable the IExecutorService on certain nodes (open source edition)?

I would like to use some nodes exclusively for data storage and other purposes, and any other node can send a Runnable to execute on these instances, if the instances have the Runnable class on the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature, neither in Open Source not Enterprise. However Enterprise would offer the option to prevent clients from submitting operations to an IExecutorService to nodes but again not for specific nodes, just for all of them.

I see two options:

- Separate the clusters into distinct
- Implement a custom wrapper and use the MemberSelector interface to select nodes able to execute IExecutorService calls